# SharePoint 2016 CU/PU/Feature Pack recommendations?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, cumulative-update

I do understand that

- CU is released on a monthly basis and contains bug fixes
- PU may be released on a monthly basis and contains security fixes
- Feature pack is released on a yearly basis and contains new features, bug fixes & security fixes

and

- CU should be installed only when it is required
- PU should be installed ASAP
- Feature pack should be installed in a month or two after the release.

Now I have the following queries

- Is January 2018 CU a CU or PU? I has security fix as well.
- What is the recommended frequency for CU installation? I do understand that it should be installed on a demand basis however just trying to see if there are any other recommendations.
- What happens when I skip last 3 CUs and wanted to install the current CU? should I install all the CUs that are missed?
- Can I just keep installing PUs without having to install CUs?
- Finally, what is recommended for Feature Pack installation?

Comment: So is the Security Patches for SharePoint 2016 released with WSUS the same as SharePoint PU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now a days MSFT releasing two things, security updates and PU (also be CU) on monthly basis. What I understand on [MSFT official site](https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/mt782882(v=office.16).aspx) they called it public update but Stefan called it cu on his msdn blog. For me it is two name for one update.

- Jan 2018 is sharepoint update can call CU or PU, as I said earlier. This update include the security fix.
- Now MSFT guideline is ASAP.Microsoft recommends that all customers install Public Updates for SharePoint Server 2016 as soon as they become available. Microsoft performs rigorous validation of each Public Update, both internally and with a select set of partners and customers before it is released to ensure it has the highest quality.
- updates are culamalitve, that's mean include all previous cu/ security fixes, so if you miss 3 and want to install latest then it will cover all.
- there is no separate PU or Cu for SharePoint 2016, it is the name of same updates. So you dont need to worry.There are may be separate security updates. Make sure when u patch your SharePoint farm, must install both packages( without language and language dependent)
- feature pack is also part of updates, there is no separate release for it.like before we were seeing service pack but no more. So if you are on Jan 2018 CU/PU then both features packs already installed.

Official Recommendation is install updates asap when they available.but, I would test it in lower farm then go to production.read the q&a section of above mentioned link.

Comment: Does it mean security update is different from CU/PU? if so, are they released separately?

Comment: All I want to make sure is that we don't either miss the security update or impact the system by installing the unnecessary CU/PU?

Comment: Is language independent package same as security update? Can we just install the language independent package alone? Is it recommend to install both the packages together?

Comment: Yes security updates released separately as well. They are also part of CU. If you see the description of language independent patch, they called it security update as well because in that package they include all updated related to security as well as SharePoint fix and improvements.

Comment: You must install both packages LP independent and dependent, it is the Msft guideline. So install both followed by config wizard.